# Undefined index: key php error

Tags: php, mysql, ionic2

**Notice: Undefined index: key in C:\xampp\htdocs\ionic-api\manage-data.php on line 22**

it says that line 22 is the error, but i cant still figure out to resolve

```
$key  = strip_tags($_REQUEST['key']);
```

im new to ionic 2, im just trying to connect ionic to mysql through php but im stuck to this error

```
<?php
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

   // Define database connection parameters
   $hn      = 'localhost';
   $un      = 'root';
   $pwd     = 'password';
   $db      = 'todo';
   $cs      = 'utf8';

   // Set up the PDO parameters
   $dsn  = "mysql:host=" . $hn . ";port=3306;dbname=" . $db . ";charset=" . $cs;
   $opt  = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE           => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE > PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                       );
   // Create a PDO instance (connect to the database)
   $pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $un, $pwd, $opt);

   // Retrieve specific parameter from supplied URL
   $key  = strip_tags($_REQUEST['key']);
   $data    = array();


   // Determine which mode is being requested
   switch($key)
   {

      // Add a new record to the technologies table
      case "create":

         // Sanitise URL supplied values
         $name       = filter_var($_REQUEST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $description   = filter_var($_REQUEST['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);

         // Attempt to run PDO prepared statement
         try {
            $sql  = "INSERT INTO technologies(name, description) VALUES(:name, :description)";
            $stmt    = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was added to the database'));
         }
         // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;



      // Update an existing record in the technologies table
      case "update":

         // Sanitise URL supplied values
         $name          = filter_var($_REQUEST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $description   = filter_var($_REQUEST['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $recordID      = filter_var($_REQUEST['recordID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

         // Attempt to run PDO prepared statement
         try {
            $sql  = "UPDATE technologies SET name = :name, description = :description WHERE id = :recordID";
            $stmt =  $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':recordID', $recordID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode('Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was updated');
         }
         // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;



      // Remove an existing record in the technologies table
      case "delete":

         // Sanitise supplied record ID for matching to table record
         $recordID   =  filter_var($_REQUEST['recordID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

         // Attempt to run PDO prepared statement
         try {
            $pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $un, $pwd);
            $sql  = "DELETE FROM technologies WHERE id = :recordID";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':recordID', $recordID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode('Congratulations the record ' . $name . ' was removed');
         }
         // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;
   }

?>
```

Comment: What is the supplied url

Comment: http://localhost/ionic-api/manage-data.php 
but it gives me an error response

Comment: in your url what is key as $_REQUEST['key']

Comment: It simply says that $_REQUEST doesn't have a key named 'key'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your script is written requires that a request **key** exists as the switch needs it to then do a create, delete etc. 
Just as Scott suggested you need to definitely check if the key value exists with something like

```
$default = 'create'; 
$key  = isset($_REQUEST['key'])? strip_tags($_REQUEST['key']) : $default;
```

Or you need to have a default action in your switch too where if a key has no matched case value then you do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['key'])) { 
....
```